# Look for keywords and copy to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have a working code that does exactly what I want it to do, loops through a particular part of an excel document looking for certain keywords, then pasting those keywords into a separate sheet in the excel spreadsheet. It is just very long and doesn't allow for any more than 10 repetitions. I was wondering if anyone had advice on making this code loop until the user selects vbNo when asked if they have any more keywords?

```
Option Compare Text

Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+h
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim lastLine As Long
Dim findWhat As String
Dim toCopy As Boolean
Dim cell As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

findWhat = CStr(InputBox("What word would you like to search for today?"))
lastLine = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
If findWhat = "" Then Exit Sub
j = 1
s = 2

For i = 1 To lastLine
    For Each cell In Range("BU1").Offset(i - 1, 0)
        If InStr(cell.Text, findWhat) <> 0 Then
            toCopy = True
        End If
    Next
    If toCopy = True Then

        Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets(s).Rows(j)
        j = j + 1
    End If
    toCopy = False
Next
s = s + 1

If MsgBox(((j - 1) & " results were copied, do you have more keywords to enter?"), vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

findWhat = CStr(InputBox("What word would you like to search for today?"))
lastLine = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
If findWhat = "" Then Exit Sub
j = 1
For i = 1 To lastLine
    For Each cell In Range("BU1").Offset(i - 1, 0)
        If InStr(cell.Text, findWhat) <> 0 Then
            toCopy = True
        End If
    Next
    If toCopy = True Then
        Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets(s).Rows(j)
        j = j + 1
    End If
    toCopy = False
Next
s = s + 1
If MsgBox(((j - 1) & " results were copied, do you have more keywords to enter?"), vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

findWhat = CStr(InputBox("What word would you like to search for today?"))
lastLine = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
If findWhat = "" Then Exit Sub
j = 1
For i = 1 To lastLine
    For Each cell In Range("BU1").Offset(i - 1, 0)
        If InStr(cell.Text, findWhat) <> 0 Then
            toCopy = True
        End If
    Next
    If toCopy = True Then
        Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets(s).Rows(j)
        j = j + 1
    End If
    toCopy = False
Next
s = s + 1
If MsgBox(((j - 1) & " results were copied, do you have more keywords to enter?"), vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

findWhat = CStr(InputBox("What word would you like to search for today?"))
lastLine = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
If findWhat = "" Then Exit Sub
j = 1
For i = 1 To lastLine
    For Each cell In Range("BU1").Offset(i - 1, 0)
        If InStr(cell.Text, findWhat) <> 0 Then
            toCopy = True
        End If
    Next
    If toCopy = True Then
        Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets(s).Rows(j)
        j = j + 1
    End If
    toCopy = False
Next
s = s + 1
If MsgBox(((j - 1) & " results were copied, do you have more keywords to enter?"), vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

findWhat = CStr(InputBox("What word would you like to search for today?"))
lastLine = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
If findWhat = "" Then Exit Sub
j = 1
For i = 1 To lastLine
    For Each cell In Range("BU1").Offset(i - 1, 0)
        If InStr(cell.Text, findWhat) <> 0 Then
            toCopy = True
        End If
    Next
    If toCopy = True Then
        Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets(s).Rows(j)
        j = j + 1
    End If
    toCopy = False
Next
s = s + 1
If MsgBox(((j - 1) & " results were copied, do you have more keywords to enter?"), vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

findWhat = CStr(InputBox("What word would you like to search for today?"))
lastLine = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
If findWhat = "" Then Exit Sub
j = 1
For i = 1 To lastLine
    For Each cell In Range("BU1").Offset(i - 1, 0)
        If InStr(cell.Text, findWhat) <> 0 Then
            toCopy = True
        End If
    Next
    If toCopy = True Then
        Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets(s).Rows(j)
        j = j + 1
    End If
    toCopy = False
Next
s = s + 1
If MsgBox(((j - 1) & " results were copied, do you have more keywords to enter?"), vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

findWhat = CStr(InputBox("What word would you like to search for today?"))
lastLine = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
If findWhat = "" Then Exit Sub
j = 1
For i = 1 To lastLine
    For Each cell In Range("BU1").Offset(i - 1, 0)
        If InStr(cell.Text, findWhat) <> 0 Then
            toCopy = True
        End If
    Next
    If toCopy = True Then
        Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets(s).Rows(j)
        j = j + 1
    End If
    toCopy = False
Next
s = s + 1
If MsgBox(((j - 1) & " results were copied, do you have more keywords to enter?"), vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

findWhat = CStr(InputBox("What word would you like to search for today?"))
lastLine = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
If findWhat = "" Then Exit Sub
j = 1
For i = 1 To lastLine
    For Each cell In Range("BU1").Offset(i - 1, 0)
        If InStr(cell.Text, findWhat) <> 0 Then
            toCopy = True
        End If
    Next
    If toCopy = True Then
        Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets(s).Rows(j)
        j = j + 1
    End If
    toCopy = False
Next
s = s + 1
If MsgBox(((j - 1) & " results were copied, do you have more keywords to enter?"), vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

findWhat = CStr(InputBox("What word would you like to search for today?"))
lastLine = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
If findWhat = "" Then Exit Sub
j = 1
For i = 1 To lastLine
    For Each cell In Range("BU1").Offset(i - 1, 0)
        If InStr(cell.Text, findWhat) <> 0 Then
            toCopy = True
        End If
    Next
    If toCopy = True Then
        Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets(s).Rows(j)
        j = j + 1
    End If
    toCopy = False
Next
s = s + 1
If MsgBox(((j - 1) & " results were copied, do you have more keywords to enter?"), vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

findWhat = CStr(InputBox("What word would you like to search for today?"))
lastLine = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
If findWhat = "" Then Exit Sub
j = 1
For i = 1 To lastLine
    For Each cell In Range("BU1").Offset(i - 1, 0)
        If InStr(cell.Text, findWhat) <> 0 Then
            toCopy = True
        End If
    Next
    If toCopy = True Then
        Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets(s).Rows(j)
        j = j + 1
    End If
    toCopy = False
Next
s = s + 1
If MsgBox(((j - 1) & " results were copied, do you have more keywords to enter?"), vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

findWhat = CStr(InputBox("What word would you like to search for today?"))
lastLine = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
If findWhat = "" Then Exit Sub
j = 1
For i = 1 To lastLine
    For Each cell In Range("BU1").Offset(i - 1, 0)
        If InStr(cell.Text, findWhat) <> 0 Then
            toCopy = True
        End If
    Next
    If toCopy = True Then
        Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets(s).Rows(j)
        j = j + 1
    End If
    toCopy = False
Next
s = s + 1
If MsgBox(((j - 1) & " results were copied, do you have more keywords to enter?"), vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

findWhat = CStr(InputBox("What word would you like to search for today?"))
lastLine = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
If findWhat = "" Then Exit Sub
j = 1
For i = 1 To lastLine
    For Each cell In Range("BU1").Offset(i - 1, 0)
        If InStr(cell.Text, findWhat) <> 0 Then
            toCopy = True
        End If
    Next
    If toCopy = True Then
        Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets(s).Rows(j)
        j = j + 1
    End If
    toCopy = False
Next
s = s + 1
If MsgBox(((j - 1) & " results were copied, do you have more keywords to enter?"), vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

findWhat = CStr(InputBox("What word would you like to search for today?"))
lastLine = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
If findWhat = "" Then Exit Sub
j = 1
For i = 1 To lastLine
    For Each cell In Range("BU1").Offset(i - 1, 0)
        If InStr(cell.Text, findWhat) <> 0 Then
            toCopy = True
        End If
    Next
    If toCopy = True Then
        Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets(s).Rows(j)
        j = j + 1
    End If
    toCopy = False
Next
s = s + 1
If MsgBox(((j - 1) & " results were copied, do you have more keywords to enter?"), vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

findWhat = CStr(InputBox("What word would you like to search for today?"))
lastLine = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
If findWhat = "" Then Exit Sub
j = 1
For i = 1 To lastLine
    For Each cell In Range("BU1").Offset(i - 1, 0)
        If InStr(cell.Text, findWhat) <> 0 Then
            toCopy = True
        End If
    Next
    If toCopy = True Then
        Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets(s).Rows(j)
        j = j + 1
    End If
    toCopy = False
Next
s = s + 1
If MsgBox(((j - 1) & " results were copied, do you have more keywords to enter?"), vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

findWhat = CStr(InputBox("What word would you like to search for today?"))
lastLine = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
If findWhat = "" Then Exit Sub
j = 1
For i = 1 To lastLine
    For Each cell In Range("BU1").Offset(i - 1, 0)
        If InStr(cell.Text, findWhat) <> 0 Then
            toCopy = True
        End If
    Next
    If toCopy = True Then
        Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets(s).Rows(j)
        j = j + 1
    End If
    toCopy = False
Next
s = s + 1
If MsgBox(((j - 1) & " results were copied, do you have more keywords to enter?"), vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

findWhat = CStr(InputBox("What word would you like to search for today?"))
lastLine = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
If findWhat = "" Then Exit Sub
j = 1
For i = 1 To lastLine
    For Each cell In Range("BU1").Offset(i - 1, 0)
        If InStr(cell.Text, findWhat) <> 0 Then
            toCopy = True
        End If
    Next
    If toCopy = True Then
        Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets(s).Rows(j)
        j = j + 1
    End If
    toCopy = False
Next
s = s + 1
If MsgBox(((j - 1) & " results were copied, do you have more keywords to enter?"), vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

findWhat = CStr(InputBox("What word would you like to search for today?"))
lastLine = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
If findWhat = "" Then Exit Sub
j = 1
For i = 1 To lastLine
    For Each cell In Range("BU1").Offset(i - 1, 0)
        If InStr(cell.Text, findWhat) <> 0 Then
            toCopy = True
        End If
    Next
    If toCopy = True Then
        Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets(s).Rows(j)
        j = j + 1
    End If
    toCopy = False
Next
s = s + 1
```

Comment: This would be a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ as the code is working and you are looking to improve it. It would get better reception there. If you do post it there, make sure you delete it on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'd start with extracting some [functions](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/differen.htm) for repetitive code.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am new to the site and appreciate the advice.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you ask for a review of working code. You could and schould first check the help center of codereview.se and their meta if they are open for these kind of questions. On Stack Overflow this is off-topic

Comment: The code actually doesn't entirely work.  They wish to make this work for an indefinite amount of words and it only works for 20.  Perhaps the question could be written to more clearly state this.

Comment: I posted to code review and they stated that they don't usually work with "adding features" so I assume they just work with debugging, am I correct there?

Comment: aaaand no you aren't. Please read through the [rules](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) of a site before assuming things  ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is make a loop that will continue until the user chooses to stop by hitting cancel in your input box.  To start the loop, set the loop check variable, "continue" to be equal to the result of clicking 'yes' on the box that asks if the user wants to continue.

Then, after executing the code, ask the user if they wish to add another word.  If not, the loop will end.  If so, the loop will continue and do another word.

Here's a start....

```
Dim Continue As Long
Dim findWhat As String
Dim LastLine As Long
Dim toCopy As Boolean
Dim cell As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim newsheet As Worksheet

s = 2

Continue = vbYes 'initialize loop variable
    Do While Continue = vbYes 'keep getting more use input until they state they do not want to continue

        findWhat = CStr(InputBox("What word would you like to search for today?"))
        lastLine = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If findWhat = "" Then Exit Sub
        j = 1
    For i = 1 To lastLine
        For Each cell In Range("BU1").Offset(i - 1, 0)
            If InStr(cell.Text, findWhat) <> 0 Then
                toCopy = True
            End If
        Next
        If toCopy = True Then
            Set newsheet = activeworkbook.sheets.add
            newsheet.name = findWhat
            Rows(i).Copy Destination:=newsheet.Rows(j)
            j = j + 1
        End If
        Set newsheet = Nothing
        toCopy = False
    Next i
    s = s + 1
    'find out if user wishes to continue.
    Continue = MsgBox(((j - 1) & " results were copied, do you have more keywords to enter?"), vbYesNo + vbQuestion)
Loop
```

Comment: This is a great starting point, thank you. One thing I had to do to make it work was remove the '=vbNo' after the msgbox. Thank you!

Comment: Also, do you know of a way that I can have it automatically create a sheet with the name of the sheet being the user input? and would it go in after the "If toCopy = True Then" line?

Comment: Hiya there! While this may actually answer the question, not everyone is as knowledgeable as you are. Mind adding a little explanation? Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, I have also edited the code to have the s=2 come before the loop so that it will increment properly instead of resetting to two everytime it loops. How would I go about having the new sheet added to the end of the workbook instead of the beginning? I tried " Worksheets.Add After:=Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count)" and it threw an error.

Comment: @Vogel612, it looks like he is having it add a new sheet and setting the sheet name to be equal to the user input at the beginning of the loop. If the code ends after finding all the results, it will not create a new sheet.

Comment: @wesree um.. I am not actually interested in what it does. It's more the "quality" of the answer I am concerned with. I hope that Q&A around here can teach people how to fish, instead of giving them their daily dose of fish to survive.... An answer that contains only code doesn't accomplish that goal IMO, so I write these comments

Comment: Try "Worksheets.add after:=Activeworkbook.sheets(activeworkbook.sheets.count)"

Comment: @Vigel612, that's a great point.  I've added some more explanation to the code.